# cakephp 2.6 security request black-holed from another view

Tags: php, security, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i red a lot about black holed requests in cakephp but i didn't found a working solution for my problem.

In my application i am using the login form in several places, so i created a reusable element. like:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form', 'url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')));
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control'));
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

(*Note*: url to controller and action in form)

If i click the form's send button in `foo.com/users/login` i got redirected to users/view in success or back to users/login in failure. After that i press the browsers page return button to get back to the form and again click the send button all works fine and the login is checked again. But if i do the same in for example `foo.com/pages/home` i get a request black-holed exception in the second continues (the first works fine).

If i deactivate the security component all works fine, but this is not what i want.

How can i prevent this?

I also recognized that the securtiy component is by default not available? Is this true?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: security component prevents user from re hitting the form , i guess you are re hitting the form in your test.

Comment: but how can i handle this? it is not ver user-friendly. Can i automatically refresh the page if the user hit the page back button so a new token is generated? What is the recommended way to handle it?

Comment: you can re validate a page if user clicks back button

Comment: can you show me a example or link to cakephp book?

Comment: you are using 'controller' => 'uses', 'action' => 'login', are you sure you want uses controller rather than users controller

Comment: $this->disableCache(); should work

Comment: it is just a typo. How to place the disableCache function? in login action?

Comment: i am wondering why it is working if i send the request from `foo.com/users/login` but not from another view.

Comment: $this->response->disableCache(); did it! thank you so much. In my case i have to put it into PagesController's display action. Post your answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security component prevents user from re hitting the form.
When user press back button you can re-validate a page using

`$this->response->disableCache();`